# JFrame contains ToolBar with a JButton, press button put an existing panel on frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtoolbar

It's been 13 years since I last worked with Java and I'm lost. Someone please toss me a life saver.

I want to add the `JPanel` requesting the address to display on the `JFrame` by adding it from a `JToolBar`. Each component is in a separate class.

Question is, the button is on a toolbar and the panel I want to add is a separate class. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you just need a button click event that toggles the display of the JPanel? Make a method in the JPanel class that toggles the correct visibility of components and call it from the button click event.

Comment: Display a modal JDialog with your panel. When the dialog is closed you copy the data from the dialog to your JTable.

Comment: Further clarification, all my previous Java experience was backend.Would it be better to use a menu item instead of a toolbar. to add a JPanel to the original JPanel.

Comment: Tip: Add @sorifiend (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: *"Would it be better to use a menu item instead of a toolbar(?)"* It should make no difference. *"to add a JPanel to the original JPanel"* Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: @camickr, thanks, your suggestion worked. It seems that my rusty Java backend also helped me forget OOP principles

Comment: @sorifiend, thanks for the @ tip